# Update items name in a combobox vba access

Tags: file, ms-access, combobox, vba

I have some code that adds the files stored in a folder into a combobox one by one, but when I run the code and use the combobox all the names are shown with their filename extension (.accdb).
Is there a way to fix this issue? Thanks for any help.

Here's the code that I'm using to add the items into the combobox.

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim FSOtry As FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Folder
Dim FileItem As File

Set FSOtry = New FileSystemObject
Set SourceFolder = FSOtry.GetFolder("C:\Users\melhani\Downloads\backendDBS")

For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    comboTry.AddItem (FileItem.Name)

    Next FileItem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `comboTry.AddItem (FileItem.Name)` to:

```
comboTry.AddItem Left(FileItem.Name, InStrRev(FileItem.Name, ".") - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fancy expression:

```
comboTry.AddItem (StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(FileItem.Name), ".", 2)(1)))
```

Comment: That's a pretty twisted one, but I might try it out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah. The feature is, that it allows for multiple dots in the full filename.